# Creating HttpURLConnection for URLStreamHandlerFactory, getting Error: protocol doesn't support input

Tags: java, http, javafx, request, interceptor

A bit of background, I'm trying to create a URL Stream Handler so I can keep track of how many connections I have active on my webview in my javafx application.  Essentially, I'm running an AngularJs app in the WebView, and I'd like to know when it's finished.  I can't touch the web site code, so adding a js notifier is not on the table.  So, no matter what I put together, the setup always errors with 'protocol doesn't support input.'  I've tried to override 'getDoInput' with a method that only returns false, but I still get the error.  Any ideas?

Here is something close to what I'm doing:

```
public class MyUrlStreamHandlerFactory implements URLStreamHandlerFactory {

    public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
        if (protocol.equalsIgnoreCase("http") || protocol.equalsIgnoreCase("https")) {

            return new URLStreamHandler() {
                @Override
                protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {

                    return new HttpURLConnection(url) {
                        @Override
                        public void connect() throws IOException {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void disconnect() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean usingProxy() {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean getDoInput() {
                            return false;
                        }
                    };

                }
            };

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm installing it with:

```
URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new MyUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
```

Comment: The only thing we can do with the statement *"here is something close to what I'm doing"* is guess at what might be causing the error. Please post the relevant code to what you're actually doing.

Comment: This is the current state of the code as it exists in the project, other than an int member and a ++ and -- within connect and disconnect, respectively.  I omitted that, as incrementing and decrementing is innocuous to the problem.  I haven't progressed any further as I cannot determine why it produces the error 'protocol doesn't support input.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you're trying to accomplish however, I think this is the wrong way to go about it.

> **From:** [Java Network Programming by Elliotte Rusty Harold](https://books.google.com/books?id=LXsgAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT285&ots=H-snX4lzGe&dq=Java%20should%20I%20subclass%20URLStreamHandler&pg=PT286#v=onepage&q&f=false)
>
> Only abstract `URLConnection` classes are present in the `java.net` package. The concrete subclasses are hidden inside the `sun.net` package hierarchy. It is rare to instantiate `URLConnection` objects directly in your source code; instead, the runtime environment creates these objects as needed, depending on the protocol in use. The class (which is unknown at compile time) is then instantiated using the `forName()` and `newInstance()` methods of the `java.lang.Class` class.
>
> For example, the `connect()` method of `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` creates a `sun.net.www.http.HttpClient` object, which is responsible for connecting to the server.

So unless you want to write your own http protocol handler and an HttpClient, I would suggest exploring other avenues.

### Other Things

The only method, that I could find, that throws an `UnknownServiceException` with the message being `"protocol doesn't support input"` is:

#### java.net.URLConnection#getInputStream

```
/**
* Returns an input stream that reads from this open connection.
*
* @return     an input stream that reads from this open connection.
* @exception  IOException              if an I/O error occurs while
*               creating the input stream.
* @exception  UnknownServiceException  if the protocol does not support
*               input.
*/
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    throw new UnknownServiceException("protocol doesn't support input");
}
```

**Overriding `getDoInput`**
You should not override `getDoInput` to only return false. Instead you should use `setDoInput(false)`. However, you don't want to set `doInput` to false. You always want to read something, for instance the response code.

Comment: I ended up extending sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection, which goes along with the first part of your answer.

Comment: @freeman_irl how did you manage to override `getInputStream()` then?