# Can't connect and read a web page

Tags: java

I'm trying to establish a http connection and read the contents of a HTML page. This is the class I'm using to connect to a page,

```
public class Connection {

    private URL url;
    private HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;


    public Connection(String url) throws MalformedURLException {

        this.url = new URL(url);
        this.httpURLConnection = new HttpURLConnection(this.url) {
            @Override
            public void connect() throws IOException {

                httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

            }

            @Override
            public void disconnect() {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean usingProxy() {
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

    public String parse() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\n');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the calling code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        String url = "https://www.buffalo.edu";
        Connection c;
        String str = null;
        try {
            c = new Connection(url);
            str = c.parse();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

I get the following Exception

```
 null
java.net.UnknownServiceException: protocol doesn't support input
    at java.net.URLConnection.getInputStream(URLConnection.java:830)
    at io.soumasish.connections.Connection.parse(Connection.java:47)
    at io.soumasish.App.main(App.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

What am I doing wrong here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong usage of `HttpURLConnection`. It's a loop of `connect()` which does nothing

```
this.httpURLConnection = new HttpURLConnection(this.url) {
    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
       httpURLConnection.connect();
       ...
```

The correct pattern of HttpURLConnection Class is mentioned here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Net.HttpURLConnection/

Modify your `Connection()` like below will make it work.

```
public Connection(String url) throws IOException {
    this.url = new URL(url);
    this.httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) this.url.openConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good explanation of the same issue here on this thread as to why this is failing ([Creating HttpURLConnection for URLStreamHandlerFactory, getting Error: protocol doesn't support input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993995/creating-httpurlconnection-for-urlstreamhandlerfactory-getting-error-protocol)).

The book is referenced here as well (https://books.google.de/books?id=LXsgAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT285&ots=H-snX4lzGe&dq=Java+should+I+subclass+URLStreamHandler&pg=PT286&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=connect()&f=false)